# Pandas Data Frames: Getting an Element in a Column by Month in Datetime Index?

Tags: python, pandas

I've managed to group a data frame by Datetime month doing this:

```
df.set_index('Date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).sum()
```

The data looks like this:

```
           price, debt
2018-4-30, 40.0, 50,0
2018-5-31, 10.0, 0.0
2018-6-30, 30.0, 0.0
2018-7-31, 30.0, 10.0
```

When I run `print(df.index)`, it gives me this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-6-30', '2018-7-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq='M')
```

Is there a way to match a column by the Month/year in the index? So, if I wanted to get a price in July of 2018, it'll return `30.0`. If not, what is the best way to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) by year and months with [`item`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html) for convert one element `Series` to scalar:

```
print(df['2018-07']['price'].item())
30.0
```

Or use grouping by `MS` for start of string and select by loc with first day:

```
df = df.set_index('Date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS')).sum()
print (df)
            price  debt
Date                   
2018-04-01   40.0  50.0
2018-05-01   10.0   0.0
2018-06-01   30.0   0.0
2018-07-01   30.0  10.0

print(df.loc['2018-07-01', 'price'])
30.0
```

Another solution is convert datetimes to month period by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')
df = df.groupby('Date').sum()
print (df)
         price  debt
Date                
2018-04   40.0  50.0
2018-05   10.0   0.0
2018-06   30.0   0.0
2018-07   30.0  10.0

print (df.loc['2018-07', 'price'])
30.0
```

If use some old version of pandas also working (thanks [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056641/pandas-data-frames-getting-an-element-in-a-column-by-month-in-datetime-index/50056714?noredirect=1#comment87130739_50056714) ):

```
df.loc['2018-07', 'price']
```

but in `pandas 0.22.0` get:

> KeyError: 'the label [2018-07] is not in the [index]'

Comment: Given that there is only one date per month, just using `df.loc['2018-07', 'price']` should work fine, no?

Comment: @Alexander - with datetimeindex not.

Comment: @Alexander get `KeyError: 'the label [2018-07] is not in the [index]'`

Comment: I'm using an older version of Pandas (0.17.1, don't ask...), and it works fine.